# Add new attribute to JSON

Tags: json, node.js, sequelize.js

Using Node js and Sequelize ORM, i'm getting a data set. I need to add a new attribute to received data and send it to client side. This is what i tried.

**Code Block 1**

```
var varAddOns = { "id" : 5, "Name" : "Cheese"};

global.meal.findOne(
        {
            where: { id: 5 }
        }).then(varMeal => {
            var obj = {};
            obj = varMeal;
            obj.addons = varAddOns;
            res.send(obj); 
        });
```

It returns a json like below. (Actually it does not contain "addons" data)

**Code Block 2**

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "mealName": "Burger",    
    "description": "Oily food",    
}
```

but actually what i want is,

**Code Block 3**

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "mealName": "Burger",    
    "description": "Oily food",   
    "addons" : { 
              "id" : 5, 
              "Name" : "Cheese"
           }
}
```

I tried something like below and it also wont work. (It returns same json as "Code Block 2'.)

**Code Block 4**

```
 var newJson = {};
 newJson = JSON.stringify(varMeal);
 newJson['addons'] = varAddOns;
 var retVal = JSON.parse(newJson);
 res.send(retVal);
```

Can you help me to figure out, where the issue is?

> EDIT

**Code Block 5**

```
var newJson = {};
newJson = varMeal;
newJson['addons'] = varAddOn;
var retVal = newJson;// JSON.parse(newJson);
res.send(retVal);
```

I tried 'Code block 5' as well. Same result comes out as 'Code block 2'. When I use  JSON.parse(newJson), it was thrown an error. (Error is *Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1*)

Comment: *"Can you help me to figure out, where the issue is?"* -- You didn't understand what [JSON](http://json.org) is. It is a text representation of some data structure. You want to add properties to the data structure (before representing it as JSON) and not to the JSON. The JSON representation is a string, adding properties to it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.get` on your model instance, and then attach extra properties to it:

```
var varAddOns = { "id" : 5, "Name" : "Cheese"};

global.meal.findOne(
        {
            where: { id: 5 }
        }).then(varMeal => {
            var obj = {};
            obj = varMeal.get();
            obj.addons = varAddOns;
            res.send(obj); 
        });
```

A few things:

- When you call `findOne`, Sequelize return a model instance, not a plain JS object with your data.
- If you want to add extra properties to send to your user, you will first need to convert your model instance to a JS object with your data. You can do this by calling `varMeal.get()`. From there, you can add extra properties to it.
- There is no need to prepend your variables with "var". It would be better to simply name your variable `meal`

Answer (score 0):

you need the JSON to be an object when you are declaring `newJson['addons']` as a nested object

Have you tried (in code block 4) not stringifying varMeal?

Comment: Yes. it also wont work. I've edited my OP and added code block 5 as per your direction.